# TypeError: 'Board' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

The problem is in `check_win(self, player):` function in `class Board:` in line `for row in range(self, board_rows):`
my code is here:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pathlib import *
import numpy as np

'''
---------
CONSTANTS
---------
'''
base_directory = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
icon_path = 'tic_tac_toe_resources/images/tic_tac_toe.ico'
full_icon_path = base_directory / icon_path
width = height = 600
line_width = 14
board_rows = 3
board_columns = 3
box_size = width // board_columns
circle_radius = box_size // 3
cross_box_space = box_size // 4
circle_width = cross_width = 24
screen_color = (28, 170, 156)
line_color = (23, 145, 135)
circle_color = (1, 111, 124)
cross_color = (65, 65, 65)

class Board:
  def __init__(self):
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    self.icon = pygame.image.load(full_icon_path)
    pygame.display.set_icon(self.icon)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tic Tac Toe by ZamaaN')
    self.screen.fill(screen_color)
    self.console_board = np.zeros((board_rows, board_columns))

  def draw_board(self):
    #? first horizontal line
    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, line_color, (11, box_size), (width - 11, box_size), line_width)

    #? second horizontal line
    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, line_color, (11, 2 * box_size), (width - 11, 2 * box_size), line_width)

    #? first vertical line
    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, line_color, (box_size, 11), (box_size, height - 11), line_width)

    #? second vertical line
    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, line_color, (2 * box_size, 11),
                     (2 * box_size, height - 11), line_width)

  def draw_figures(self):
    for row in range(board_rows):
        for column in range(board_columns):
            if self.console_board[row][column] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, circle_color, (int(column * box_size + box_size // 2), int(row * box_size + box_size // 2)), circle_radius, circle_width)

            elif self.console_board[row][column] == 2:
                pygame.draw.line(self.screen, cross_color, (column * box_size + cross_box_space, row * box_size + box_size - cross_box_space), (column *box_size + box_size - cross_box_space, row * box_size + cross_box_space), cross_width)

                pygame.draw.line(self.screen, cross_color, (column * box_size + cross_box_space, row * box_size + cross_box_space), (column *box_size + box_size - cross_box_space, row * box_size + box_size - cross_box_space), cross_width)

  def mark_box(self, row, column, player):
    self.console_board[row][column] = player

  def is_box_available(self, row, column):
    return self.console_board[row][column] == 0

  def is_board_full(self):
    for row in range(board_rows):
        for column in range(board_columns):
            if self.console_board[row][column] == 0:
                return False
    
    return True

  def draw_vertical_winning_line(self, column, player):
    position_x = column * box_size + box_size // 2

    if player == 1:
        vertical_winning_line_color = circle_color
    elif player == 2:
        vertical_winning_line_color = cross_color

    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, vertical_winning_line_color, (position_x, 14), (position_x, height - 14), 14)

def draw_horizontal_winning_line(self, row, player):
    position_y = row * box_size + box_size // 2

    if player == 1:
        horizontal_winning_line_color = circle_color
    elif player == 2:
        horizontal_winning_line_color = cross_color

    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, horizontal_winning_line_color, (14, position_y), (width - 14, position_y), 14)

  def draw_ascending_diagonal_winning_line(self, player):
    if player == 1:
        ascending_diagonal_winning_line_color = circle_color
    elif player == 2:
        ascending_diagonal_winning_line_color = cross_color

    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, ascending_diagonal_winning_line_color, (14, height - 14), (width - 14, 14), 14)

  def draw_descending_diagonal_winning_line(self, player):
    if player == 1:
        descending_diagonal_winning_line_color = circle_color
    elif player == 2:
        descending_diagonal_winning_line_color = cross_color

    pygame.draw.line(self.screen, descending_diagonal_winning_line_color, (14, 14), (width - 14, height - 14), 14)

  def check_win(self, player):
    #? vertical win check
    for column in range(board_columns):
        if self.console_board[0][column] == player and self.console_board[1][column] == player and self.console_board[2][column] == player:
            self.draw_vertical_winning_line(column, player)
            return True

    #? horizontal win check
    for row in range(self, board_rows):
        if self.console_board[row][0] == player and self.console_board[row][1] == player and self.console_board[row][2] == player:
            self.draw_horizontal_winning_line(row, player)
            return True

    #? ascending diagonal win check
    if self.console_board[2][0] == player and self.console_board[1][1] == player and self.console_board[0][2] == player:
        self.draw_ascending_diagonal_winning_line(player)
        return True

    #? descending diagonal win check
    if self.console_board[0][0] == player and self.console_board[1][1] == player and self.console_board[2][2] == player:
        self.draw_descending_diagonal_winning_line(player)
        return True

    return False

class Game_TicTacToe:
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.board = Board()
    self.board.draw_board()
    self.player = 1

  def restart(self):
    self.board.screen.fill(screen_color)
    self.board.draw_board()

    self.player = 1

    for row in range(board_rows):
        for column in range(board_columns):
            self.board.console_board[row][column] = 0
    
  def run(self):
    running = True
    game_over = False

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                    self.restart()
                    game_over = False

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:
                mouse_x = event.pos[0]
                mouse_y = event.pos[1]
                clicked_row = int(mouse_y // box_size)
                clicked_column = int(mouse_x // box_size)

                if self.board.is_box_available(clicked_row, clicked_column):
                    self.board.mark_box(clicked_row, clicked_column, self.player)
                    if self.board.check_win(self.player):
                        game_over = True
                    
                    self.player = self.player % 2 + 1
                    self.board.draw_figures()
            
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game_TicTacToe()
    game.run()
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\tic_tac_toe_py\tic_tac_toe.py", line 192, in <module>
game.run()
File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\tic_tac_toe_py\tic_tac_toe.py", line 179, in run     
if self.board.check_win(self.player):
File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\tic_tac_toe_py\tic_tac_toe.py", line 124, in check_win
for row in range(self, board_rows):
TypeError: 'Board' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your code is not minimal, and you haven't traced the problem values.

Comment: You should get rid fo the self in that line that says `for row in range(self, board_rows):` and just have it like you have the other uses of range.

Comment: it is probably just a fallout of using the code formatting here, but `draw_horizontal_winning_line()` is not properly indented

Comment: Also, please spend some time looking at how the exception traceback maps out right where the problem is so you don't have to go to stackoverflow and get people lecturing you on asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `self` there is redundant (read: wrong). You only need the number of rows in order to iterate over them:

```py
for row in range(board_rows):
```